# EF Core: loading related entities as only ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm not sure what I want is something one should expect from EF, but I think I've seen this in other ORMs and this should be quite common for it to be solved in EF - so I'm asking if it has been.

I want to be able to eagerly load foreign key entities when querying EF, but only their ids, as the other part of objects will be loaded much later.

I have:

```
class A {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public B B { get; set; }
}

class B {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   // .... more properties
}
```

And a web API, that should return a list of all As, with this view model:

```
class AViewModel {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int BId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make sure I do not include B table join when querying - for performance reasons. I'm also using `automapper` to map from `A` to `AViewModel`.

Currently the best way I found to do this is:

```
var a = context.As;
var aList = a.Select(x => new { model = x, bid = x.B.Id }).ToList();
return Ok(mapper.Map<List<AViewModel>(aList));
```

Unfortunately this means that I have to add mapping from `new { model = x, bid = x.B.Id }` to `AViewModel`, that is really unconvenient.
I'd prefer to just be able to write:

```
var a = context.As;
var aList = a.ToList();
return Ok(mapper.Map<List<AViewModel>(aList));
```

But in this case it fails with `NullReferenceException`, because every item of `aList` has `B` property `null`.

I could write `context.As.Include(x => x.B)` but this will join B table, that I would like to avoid.

I think I have seen some ORMs being able to fill in `B` objects with empty objects, except for ids - and that is the behavior I'm looking for in EF. Can it do that?

If not maybe one can suggest a nicer way of solving a problem? maybe I can fix this somehow with lazy proxies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the foreignKey property on the A class:

```cs
class A {
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int BId {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("BId")] //can do this in the fluent API instead
   public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can just use the class A in the mapping with no need to load the B entity

Comment: This is concise and correct. Just wanted to add that it's not even necessary to configure the relation explicitly via attribute/fluent API if you follow the naming convention, which you do in your example. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Comment: I'm not 100% happy with this, as this forces me into having a property that I do not use anywhere except in `Automapper` config, but it is true that this is the correct and probably the nicest way of having what I want. This also surprised me how easy it was, I didn't think about this before and was expecting more complicated answer. Thanks